# Intellij: add space after double slashes in line comment

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Is there a way in Intellij IDEA (I'm using version 13) to automatically add a space to line comments between the two slashes and the text:

If I enter :

> //This is a comment

I'd like to get the following when I run a code reformat (Ctrl-Alt-L on Windows)

> // This is a comment

It's for Javascript files but should be working for other file types.

Comment: Anyone got any idea about this? Just running into it in intellij 14.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31842617/783119

Answer (score 5):

If you press `CTRL /` or `CMD /` it will put `//` at the beginning of the line and the comment will be properly indented.

```
//        comment with two indents
```

For this to work `Comment at first column` must be checked in `Editor->CodeStyle->Javascript->Wrapping and Braces->Keep when reformatting` like mentioned in another answer.

[image: screenshot]
This screenshot is for Java, but it works the same for Javascript. Just choose javascript in the menu

If you want to write multiline comment you can use `CTRL SHIFT /` or `CMD SHIFT /` That way when you go into new line, you will have one space after the comment start

```
    /*
    * there is space before this*/
```

Comment: you can open the issue request on their youtrack webpage

Comment: You are right two tabs are automatically added when using the CTRL / shortcut. However, it will be great if it could also work when you manually enter //mycomment. And when pressing CTRL+ALT+L (fromating) will automatically add the missing space/tab.