# wrong format on line comment webstorm or intellij ultimate

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Have anyone experience in intellij ultimate or webstorm adding a comment with the shortcut cmd + / ? 
I’m trying to change the following behavior from

`//This is a comment`

to

`// This is a comment`

notice the space after the // . I can work on atom and sublime as expected but I don’t know why webstorm or intellij use a different functionality, I’ve played with a flag in the code style tab called *Comment at first column* but that doesn’t change the behavior as I want it. If anyone have experience this I appreciate any solution / workaround

Already read this answer, but that is not the intended behavior, what I need to add a line comment with the proper space after //

[Intellij: add space after double slashes in line comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840544/intellij-add-space-after-double-slashes-in-line-comment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to have the line comment shortcut add a space after // in WebStorm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841706/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-line-comment-shortcut-add-a-space-after-in-webst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141701 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne, I will keep track of the ticket.